# Can Dragon Slayers teach Dragon Slayer Magic?

Tags: fairy-tail

Can Dragon Slayers teach other people Dragon Slayer Magic just like how the Dragons taught them?

Comment: I suppose they can, but there is no proof of this as we have not seen any dragon slayer teach anyone dragon slaying magic.

Comment: @Alagaros or at least people with dragon slayer magic. Come to think of it, what would qualify as dragon slayer magic? Would it be like just the fashion in which Natsu handles fire or would it also count the other various abilities he gets from being taught by Igneel (i.e. eating fire)

Comment: @Cyberson The same question goes for a dragon. What qualifies as a dragon? Is a dragonslayer in his dragon form (aka Acnologia) able to teach Dragon Slayer Magic or does he not count as a *real* dragon?

Comment: I thought gen 2 dragon slayers didn't learn their magic from dragons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Wiki](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Slayer), Dragon Slayer Magic is a form of lost magic. We know that Ultear was able to learn a form of lost magic called "[Arc of Time](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Arc_of_Time)" from Hades.

However, we know that there are currently two ways you can obtain Dragon Slayer Magic:

- Learn it from an actual Dragon.
- Implement a Dragon Lacrima into your body.

Therefore, I would say **yes**, this might be a third way to teach someone Dragon Slayer Magic.

Comment: lol, so in the comment you say it is unlikely, yet here you say it is possible? Btw the same question as I asked above, what is an *actual Dragon*? Is a dragonslayer in his dragon form an actual dragon or still just a dragon slayer? What I'm trying to ask is, would Acnologia be able to teach someone DS magic?

Comment: @PeterRaeves I posted my answer after doing some research, on the Wiki he is considered a dragon slayer. Since he uses dragon slayer magic to get into his Dragon form he still is considered a dragon slayer.